# How to resize partition after failed installation of Windows 10 via boot camp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition

I have resized my main drive from 250gb to 200gb so I could have 50gb for Windows 10. Installation via boot camp failed and I was left with two partitions.
Somehow I deleted the smaller one (for Windows) and now I can not reclaim that space and resize my main partition to its original size of 250gb.

```
➜ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         192.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data OSXRESERVED             8.0 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +192.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            140.0 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

DiskUtility:

[image: DiskUtility not showing entire free space]

I have tried resizing apfs container:

```
➜ diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk0s2 240g
Started APFS operation
Aligning grow delta to 48,000,000,000 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 240,000,000,000 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 192,000,536,576 bytes
Error: -69771: The target disk is too small for this operation
```

Does anybody know how to reclaim that "invisible" free space and how to expand my main partition?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal application window and enter the following commands.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: I tried doing that and after second command I get:


`The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Growing APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 192,000,000,000 to 250,790,436,864 bytes
Modifying partition map
Growing APFS data structures
APFS Container Resize error code is 49168
A problem occurred; undoing all changes
Modifying partition map
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures`


Do you have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I also tried turning off time machine and deleting any snapshots that may have existed but resizing still ends with the same error.

Comment: The message indicates there must be something wrong with the APFS container. You now have discovered a problem which is beyond your original question. You could try using the Disk Utility to run first aid. I would recommend backing up any important data before proceeding. You could ask a new question or modify your exist question. I do not have an answer that can fix this new problem.